# How is differential momentum assigned in multiparticle system of QFT?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, statistical-mechanics, fourier-transform, density-of-states

I've been following Schwartz's book on quantum field theory, and got stuck at page 59 on Section 5.1 'cross section' of the book which argues that the region of final state momenta is the product of the differential momentum, i.e,

$$d\Pi=\prod_{j} \frac{V}{(2\pi)^3}d^3p_{j}$$
and that this integrates to 1 as $\int d\Pi=1$.

I first interpreted $d\Pi$ to be a differential volume in the momentum hyperspace for $j$-particles (3j dimensional phase-space) and that integration is to be extended from zero to infinite momentum over the entire phase space. But I couldn't get how this particular form of $d\Pi$ is properly normalized such that the integration is equal to 1, so I gave a look on the footnote (1) right below the page 59 of textbook and found out apparently that

> "this normalization is the natural continuum limit of having discrete points $x_{i}=\frac{i}{N} L$ and wavenumber $p_{i}=\frac{2\pi}{L}\frac{i}{N}$ with $i=1,...N.$" .

This explanation was unsatisfactory to me cause I didn't see the natural grounds for assuming that the momentum be bounded by its maximum given (according to the footnote) as $p_{N}=\frac{2\pi}{L} \frac{N}{N} = \frac{2\pi}{L}$ .
From my understanding, momentum hyperspace is to be extended to infinity even for the crude model of confined particle in a box in standard 'particle in a box' problem in quantum mechanics, since the energy level is unbounded anyways for such problem and momentum eigenvalues are given as $p_{i}=\frac{2\pi}{L}{i}$ where i can be up to infinity.

So as a next step, I turned to other models than the 'particle in a box' (in which case particles are thought to be confined inside the detector of volume $V$) that would possibly give both the 'boundedness' as well as the 'quantization' of momentum as suggested by the footnote above.

First one I thought was the periodic boundary condition, but this quickly was discarded for this is not one of the lattice-like situations.

Second one was of the widely used semi-classical quantization which uses uncertainty principle loosely as $\Delta x \Delta p\simeq 2\pi $ in natural unit, but given that discrete positions are $x_{i}=\frac{i}{N} L $ in the footnote , this relation leads to $p_{i}=\frac{2\pi}{L}\frac{N}{i}$ not as $p_{i}=\frac{2\pi}{L}\frac{i}{N}$.

One another ground I thought for assuming this discreteness is by extending discrete Fourier transform taken on this discrete spatial points $x_{i}=\frac{i}{N} L$ to the realm of continuous Fourier transform where $N->\infty$ relating x and p, but I think this still doesn't make sense to arbitrarily assumes that our momentum is bounded somewhat.

Is there anything I'm missing throughout my thoughts or is there any other mental models to be considered in writing the formula for the differential region of the phase space smoothly as a natural continuum limit of discrete points?

Any help or suggestion on resolving this issue is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

To understand what $d \Pi$ is consider a free particle with momentum $\vec{p}$. The Schrödinger wave function in position space is given by:
$$
\psi(\vec{x})=\exp (i \vec{p} \cdot \vec{x})
$$
This wave function represents a plane wave traveling in the direction of $\vec{p}$.

If we confine the particle to a finite volume $V$, say a cubic box of side $L$, one common boundary condition to impose is the periodic boundary condition. This means that the wave function must be periodic in the box. For a one-dimensional box of length $L$, this condition can be written as:
$$
\psi(x)=\psi(x+L)
$$
Using the plane wave form of $\psi$, this condition implies:
$$
\exp (i p x)=\exp (i p(x+L))
$$
From this, we can deduce that:
$$
p=\frac{2 \pi}{L} \mathcal{N}
$$
where $\mathcal{N}$ is an integer. So we can see momentum space has been broken up into cells of size:
$$
\Delta p=\frac{2 \pi}{L} .
$$
For a three-dimensional box of volume $V=L^3$, the momenta in the $x, y$, and $z$ directions are quantized similarly. The allowed momenta $\vec{p}$ are given by:
$$
\vec{p}=\frac{2 \pi}{L}\left(\mathcal{N}_x, \mathcal{N}_y, \mathcal{N}_z\right)
$$
where $\mathcal{N}_x, \mathcal{N}_y$, and $\mathcal{N}_z$ are integers. small interval $d^3 p$ in momentum space, the number of allowed states in this interval is:
$$
\frac{d^3 p}{(\Delta p)^3}=\frac{d^3 p}{\left(\frac{2 \pi}{L}\right)^3}=\frac{V}{(2 \pi)^3} d^3 p
$$
Therefore, Eq. (5.8) of the textbook ($d \Pi=\prod_j \frac{V}{(2 \pi)^3} d^3 p_j$) gives the differential of the number of momenta states of the outgoing particles and I do not think the equation $\int d \Pi=1$ is correct.